# ListView destroys my changes

Tags: android, listview

In my case I have a listview and on a click on an item a imageview will appear. But if I scroll down or up the imageview will disappear. How can I "save" the state of the view?
Thanks

-- EDIT -
This is my adapter:

```
public class FeedListAdapterTab2 extends BaseAdapter {
        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<FeedItemAbos> feedItems;
        com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        View.OnClickListener onClickListener;

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        FeedItemAbos item;
        private long timestampLastClick;
        private long doubleClickQualificationSpanInMillis;
        private static final long DEFAULT_QUALIFICATION_SPAN = 200;
        String quotesID;

        TextView textViewQuotations;

        //UNIVERSAL
        private DisplayImageOptions options, optionsFeedImage;
        private ImageLoadingListener animateFirstListener = new AnimateFirstDisplayListener();

        public FeedListAdapterTab2(Activity activity, List<FeedItemAbos> feedItems, View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.feedItems = feedItems;
            this.onClickListener = onClickListener;

            //UNIVERSAL
            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_stub)
                    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
                    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .displayer(new CircleBitmapDisplayer(Color.WHITE, 5))
                    .build();
            //UNIVERSAL
            optionsFeedImage = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .cacheInMemory(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .build();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return feedItems.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
            return feedItems.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

            if (imageLoader == null)
                imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();


            final ImageView imageViewLike = (ImageView) convertView.
                    findViewById(R.id.imageViewLike);

            try {

                item = feedItems.get(position);


                    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            if ((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timestampLastClick) < doubleClickQualificationSpanInMillis) {
                                Log.e("DOUBLE", "CLICK");
                                timestampLastClick = 0;
                                ID = String.valueOf(v.getId());
                            timestampLastClick = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
//

                imageViewLike.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Log.e("id", "nice " + v.getId());
                        }
                    });
                }



            return convertView;
        }
```

On a "double-tap" on the convertview so the view of the listview, a imageview appears. But if the view is not shown again, the imageview disappears.

Comment: Post your code. So it is easy to understand for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The list adapter ([ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) or subclass) should keep the state of each item. The views that represent items are destroyed or recycled when they are no longer visible.
[ListAdapter.getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) will be called again for the item when it becomes visible again.

Comment: Yeah, but is there a opportunity to prevent this? To save the state of each view if all views are drawn

Comment: If you really want to keep the views, you may use them as your list items. Like, have an array of views in your adapter and return the array elements on getView()